# cannot link a external url, present page url acting as parent url

Tags: permalinks, pages, urls, links

please help some one cannot link a external link, my present page link is acting as parent link, if iam linking facebook.com , then my page url opens as www.mysite.com/facebook.com
please solve it. all my external links as same, even no plugins can help me, cannot link an external link. all links are of same.. please help in linking external link. may if need to change any code in css, please give the solution as soon as possible

Comment: If the answer is correct, you should mark it as accepted by clicking underneath the vote count on the tick so it goes green

Answer (score 2):

When adding an external link you need to include HTTP:// or HTTPS:// at the start of the URL to link to an external domain. Otherwise the link will be added onto the current domain.